# $\frac{1}{\sqrt1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\dots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}<2\sqrt{n}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction, proof-explanation, radicals

I'm trying to prove this by induction, but something doesn't add up. I see a solution given [here](https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/word/misc/Miscellaneous_Word_Problems.faq.question.29292.html), but it is actually proving that the expression is **greater** than $2\sqrt{n}$. I'd appreciate some insight.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/768916, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1981654 and some more – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt1%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt2%7D%2B%5Cdots%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%7D%3C2%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: Another one (from the “Related” section): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/648907/42969.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base step: 1<2.

Inductive step: $$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{j}} < 2\sqrt{n}+\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}$$
So if we prove
$$2\sqrt{n}+\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}<2\sqrt{n+1}$$ 
we are done. Indeed, that holds true: just square the left hand side sides to get
$$4n+2\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac1{n+1}<4n+3<4n+4$$
which is the square of the right end side.

Errata: I forgot the double product in the square. The proof must be amended as follows:
$$2\sqrt{n}<2\sqrt{n+1}-\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}$$ since by squaring it we get
$$4n<4n+4-4+\frac1{n+1}$$ which is trivially true.

Comment: I was trying to prove line by line, without separating the proof to separately prove using the square root, but this way is good too, I'm not convinced it could be proved "in one line".

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$ 2\sqrt{n+1}-2\sqrt n=2\cdot\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=2\cdot \frac{(n+1)-n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}<\frac 2{\sqrt n+\sqrt n}$$